# Jenkins Android abort test if it will take to long

Tags: android, junit, jenkins

I have a problem with not working tests on Jenkins - they are taking too much time. 
Jenkins run Project with more than 200 tests, some of them fails or hang out. How can I set timeout for single test and abort it and go to next test?
I assume that:

```
 [31mFAILED [0m
    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError...]]
```

means 31m need to pass to set test to failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to define a timeout for your test class: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Timeout-for-tests

Beside that you should investigate the reason why your test takes ages to fail/succeed and fix/improve it.